# How to implement Scanf while using pointers in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void south_east(int *lat, int *lon){                       // lat and lon are the pointer variables which take addresses as input  , int *lat = &latitude
  *lat = *lat - 1 ;                                       // Using the * operator to update the values at the address.
  *lon = *lon + 1;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int latitude;
  int longitude;
  scanf("Enter Latitude and Longitude %i\n %i\n", latitude, longitude);
  south_east(&latitude,&longitude);                                        // We pass the addresses so that the function above can easily modify them
  printf("Move to [%i, %i]\n", latitude, longitude );
  return 0;
}
```

```
ships.c: In function 'main':
ships.c:14:40: warning: format '%i' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
   scanf("Enter Latitude and Longitude %i\n %i\n", latitude, longitude);
                                        ^
ships.c:14:45: warning: format '%i' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 3 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
   scanf("Enter Latitude and Longitude %i\n %i\n", latitude, longitude);
                                             ^
ships.c:14:3: warning: 'longitude' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
   scanf("Enter Latitude and Longitude %i\n %i\n", latitude, longitude);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ships.c:14:3: warning: 'latitude' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

What's wrong with this? When I hardcode the values of latitude and Longitude, I get the desired output but when I use scanf() to get inputs, it gives me warinings!

Comment: scanf needs pointers to variables to write the result into them

Comment: You are not asking about implementing scanf.  You're just asking how to use it.

Comment: @Raildex Could you tell me what I need to add?

Comment: You need to add compiler flags that will generate warning that tell you exactly what is wrong with your code.

Comment: Just as a side note: It is unsafe to use `scanf` without checking the return value. See this page for further information: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line to send addresses, not values.
Also - in scanf define only what you want to read, not the message

```
printf("Enter Latitude and Longitude ");
scanf("%i %i", &latitude, &longitude);
```

Comment: when I enter the values as 21 and 12 I get this as output
'Move to [4194431, 3805185]' . I think it is outputing the address!